# Vue.js application, which fetches and displays list of seminars

Tags: javascript, promise, vue.js

I have a working application, which fetches list of events (seminars) from rest API. Functionality is quite simple: display list of seminars with possibility to filter upcoming/occured/all. The application can be found [here](http://ld-seminar.ru/).

Inspired by some Vue docs I've created such App object which contains store, some helper functions (`getDate`, `getState`) and function, which returns seminar object with transformed and ready to be displayed data:

```
var App = {
    store: new Storage("/wp-json/wp/v2/seminar"),
    //Parse date string and get date in different formats
    getDate: function (str, part) {
        "use strict";
        var y = str.slice(0, 4);
        var m = str.slice(4, 6);
        var d = str.slice(6, 8);

        var month = ["января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня", "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря"];

        if (part === "d") {
            return d;
        } else if (part === "m") {
            return m;
        } else if (part === "mm") {
            return month[parseInt(m) - 1];
        } else if (part === "y") {
            return y;
        } else {
            return y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
        }
    },

    //get state of seminar
    getState: function (str) {
        "use strict";
        return (new Date() > new Date(this.getDate(str)))
            ? "upcoming"
            : "occured";
    },

    //get object with all necessary data to display
    getSeminar: function (seminar) {
        "use strict";

        return {
            id: seminar.id,
            title: seminar.title.rendered,
            date: new Date(this.getDate(seminar.acf.date)),
            displayDate: this.getDate(seminar.acf.date),
            //occured: (new Date() > new Date(this.getDate(seminar.acf.date)),
            state: this.getState(this.getDate(seminar.acf.date)),
            time: seminar.acf.time,
            day: this.getDate(seminar.acf.date, "d"),
            month: this.getDate(seminar.acf.date, "mm"),
            year: this.getDate(seminar.acf.date, "y"),
            reporter: seminar.acf.reporter,
            place: seminar.acf.place
        };
    }
};
```

And here is code to create vue instance. I assign functions from App object to vue instance methods and in `created ()` function I fetch data and populate `seminars` attribute.

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        seminars: [],
        show: 'all'
    },
    computed: {
        title: function () {
            "use strict";
            return (this.show)
                ? "Предстоящие семинары"
                : "Архив семинаров";
        },
        count: function () {
            "use strict";
            var cnt = 0;
            var show = this.show;
            this.seminars.forEach(function (seminar) {
                if (seminar.state === show || show === 'all') {
                    cnt += 1;
                }
            });

            return cnt;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getSeminar: App.getSeminar,
        getDate: App.getDate,
        getState: App.getState
    },
    created: function () {
        "use strict";
        var vm = this;
        App.store.fetch().then(function (result) {
            result.forEach(function (seminar) {
                vm.seminars.push(vm.getSeminar(seminar));
            });
            //app.seminars = seminars;
        });
    }
});
```

There is also some code in my application, but it's not related to my question at the moment, but I'll mention it, just for completeness:

Storage class (actually looks, that I don't really need it here, because it does really nothing helpful, I use only the `fetch()` method of it):

```
/*global window, xhr*/
var Storage = function (url) {
    "use strict";
    this.baseUrl = url;

    this.get = function (id) {
        return xhr.get("get", this.baseUrl + "/" + id);
    };

    this.fetch = function () {
        return xhr.get("get", url);
    };
};

window.Storage = Storage;
```

And xhr object, which implements http request:

```
var xhr = {
    get: function (method, url) {
        "use strict";
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open(method, url);
            req.onload = function () {
                if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(req.response));
                } else {
                    reject({
                        status: this.status,
                        statusText: req.statusText
                    });
                }
            };
            req.onerror = function () {
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: req.statusText
                });
            };
            req.send();
        });

    }

};


window.xhr = xhr;
```

My general question is - do I need an `App` object, or what is best practice to implement some business logic in vue.js application? Maybe it would be better to implements data conversion and transformation inside of vue methods?

Comment: @t3chb0t, my mistake to say that. It works, except latest safari in iOS, so it doesn't really matter in this case.

Comment: @t3chb0t, Ok, thank you. I'll try to improve description.

Comment: The previous title was better... this one sounds like you app isn't working agian. Just replace _some data_ with _seminar data_ and it's ok.

Comment: @t3chb0t, Ok, I'll leave it in peace. ^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Main question

> #### do I need an App object, or what is best practice to implement some business login in vue.js application?

Well, it depends on how large of an application you create. For the sample code given, you could just move the methods from `App` to the Vue instance, unless that feels like too much coupling of the view layer and controller code.

What you describe sounds like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/). On the [*When should I used it?*](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html#when-should-i-use-it) section of the documentation, it mentions that "*A simple [global event bus](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication) may be all you need.*"

### Other feedback

#### `"use strict";` in every function

Are there any functions that should **not** have [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) invoked? If not, then just add one `"use script";` to the beginning of each file. Or are there external scripts that don't have scrict mode invoked?

#### naming of `Storage`

The Storage class doesn't appear to actually store data - it merely fetches data, as you stated:

> *actually looks, that I don't really need it here, because it does really nothing helpful, I use only `fetch()` method of it*

#### xhr class

The xhr class could be replaced by the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), or a similar tool like [reqwest](https://github.com/ded/Reqwest), [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), etc.

#### `parseInt()` without specifying *radix*

App.getDate() has the following line:

> ```
> return month[parseInt(m) - 1];
> ```

"***Always specify [the radix]** to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior*"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters)</sup>

```
 return month[parseInt(m, 10) - 1];
```

#### Assigning properties on `window`

The lines like the following:

> ```
> window.xhr = xhr;
> ```

Should be superfluous, unless of course `xhr` is defined within a function (e.g. an IIFE)...

#### Functional approach

You mentioned "*trying to do the same in functional style*" - perhaps you have already made changes like below but if not, it could really shorten things.

For instance, the `created` method could be shortened to below:

```
App.store.fetch().then(function (result) {
    this.seminars = this.seminars.concat(result.map(this.getSeminar));
}.bind(this));
```

Notice that [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is used to pass the `this` context into the callback handler, removing the need to assign `var vm = this;`.

Or instead of using `.concat()`, `.unshift()` could be used with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
App.store.fetch().then(function (result) {
    this.seminars.unshift(...result.map(this.getSeminar));
}.bind(this));
```

And an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) can remove the need to bind the function to `this`:

```
App.store.fetch().then(result => this.seminars.unshift(...result.map(this.getSeminar)));
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters</sub>

Comment: Thanks for review and comments! I agree, for small app like this it would be easier to add all methods to the Vue instance, but I wanted to keep it clean as possible. I've read about vuex and event bus in documentation, but still don't know how to use first one in real life. And after 20 days, since I've posted it, I feel that I don't like this code and also see a lot of things to improve. Now I'm trying to do the same in functional style and it looks much  more clean and better.

Comment: Great - I added a few more feeback items. I thought about suggesting using [`date.toLocaleDateString('ru-Cyrl', { month: 'long' })`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to get the month but it isn't in genitive form like you have it. If that worked, you wouldn't need to store the array `var months`...

Comment: Thanks a lot for a valuable remarks. I'll try to gather it all, and refactor my code. When I mentioned FP, I meant that I'm totally reworking it with Kefir.js and React.